# Foreach loop in view: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, view, foreach

I am buidling a mvc web application with entity framework.

Error:

> An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed
>   and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

This is the entity framework part:

Like you see I already include "Alineas" and do .ToList()

```
public IList<Kop> Handle(RetrieveKoppenForDocumentQuery query)
        {
            using (var db = new BmDataContext())
            {
                var koppen = db.Kop.Where(s => s.Document.Id == query.Id)
                    .Include(s => s.TegelAfbeelding)
                    .Include(s => s.CollageAfbeeldingen)
                    .Include(s => s.FinancieleAfbeeldingen)
                    .Include(s => s.Alineas)
                    .ToList();
                return _orderKoppenByIndex(koppen);
            }
        }
```

This is the view KopListItems.cshtml:

```
@using PGE.Bestuursmonitor.Contracts.DataTypes
@model IList<Kop>

@* Helper for recursively rendering koppen*@
@helper SortableItem(Kop kop)
{
    <div class="sortable-item" data-kopid="@kop.Id">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 title-column">
                <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i> @kop.Titel
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span>
                        @kop.KopType
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span>
                        @kop.Status
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        @if (@kop.Alineas != null) // on this line I receive the exception
                        {
                            // here I would like to do some logic
                        }
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sortable-container">
            @foreach (var subKop in kop.Koppen)
            {
                @SortableItem(subKop);
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}


@* Recursively render all kop items *@
<div id="koppen_sortable" class="sortable-container">
    @foreach (Kop kop in Model)
    {
        @SortableItem(kop);
    }
</div>
```

This is the view KoppenList.cshtml:

```
@model PGE.Bestuursmonitor.ViewModels.Koppen.IKoppenListViewModel

<h1>@Model.DocumentTitel</h1>

@* Render kop list header *@
<div id="koppen_sortable_header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7"><strong>Titel</strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <strong>Type</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <strong>Status</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <button type="button" id="btn_add_sub" class="btn btn-success" title="Kop aanmaken" role="button" onclick="BM.Koppen.LoadAddKopView(null);">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i> Kop aanmaken
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="koppen_sortable_body">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Koppen/KopListItems.cshtml", @Model.Koppen); }
</div>

@* Store document id in html DOM, so javascript can reach it from multiple places *@
<input type="hidden" id="document_id" value="@Model.DocumentId" />
```

Action in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult KoppenList(string id)
        {
            ViewBag.PageId = id;

            Document document = _retrieveStartPcDocumentQueryHandler.Handle(new RetrieveStartPcDocumentQuery());

            RetrieveKoppenForDocumentQuery query = new RetrieveKoppenForDocumentQuery
            {
                Id = document.Id
            };

            IList<Kop> koppen = _retrieveKoppenForDocumentQueryHandler.Handle(query);

            _koppenListViewModel.Koppen = koppen;
            _koppenListViewModel.DocumentTitel = document.Titel;
            _koppenListViewModel.DocumentId = document.Id;

            return View("~/Views/Koppen/KoppenList.cshtml", _koppenListViewModel);
        }
```

Like you see in KopListItems.cshtml there are 2 foreach loops. The outer foreach loop is working fine and can read "Alineas". The inner foreach which shows the sub items gives this strange error. What is going wrong? Im stuck.

Comment: try adding `.AsNoTracking()` to EF query

Comment: I try it but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution. You need to get the alineas and content also on sub level:

```
public IList<Kop> Handle(RetrieveKoppenForDocumentQuery query)
        {
            using (var db = new BmDataContext())
            {
                var koppen = db.Kop.Where(s => s.Document.Id == query.Id)
                    .Include(s => s.TegelAfbeelding)
                    .Include(s => s.CollageAfbeeldingen)
                    .Include(s => s.FinancieleAfbeeldingen)
                    .Include(s => s.Alineas.Select(a => a.Content))
                    .Include(s => s.Koppen.Select(k => k.Alineas.Select(a => a.Content)))
                    .Include(s => s.Koppen.Select(k => k.Koppen.Select(x => x.Alineas.Select(a => a.Content))))
                    .ToList();
                return _orderKoppenByIndex(koppen);
            }
        }
```